# StreamWritter with thrift server

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to process some data via spark2 stream and save them to hdfs. While stream is running i want to read the stored data via thrift server with simple select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stream_table UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thisistable;
```

But I'm getting this **exception**

> Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
>       Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
>       Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6, localhost): 
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>       hdfs://5b6b8bf723a2:9000/archiveData/parquets/efc44dd4-1792-4b6d-b0f2-120818047b1b is not a Parquet file (too small)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:412)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:385)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:371)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.getSplit(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:252)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:99)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:85)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:246)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)or$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

My assumption is that spark will create an empty parquet file at the start of the batch, and fill it at the end of the batch, and I'm running A `select` via archived files, but one is empty as the actual batch is not finished yet.

**Simple spark stream example (Thread.sleep for simulation of transformation delay)**

```
spark
    .readStream()
    .schema(schema)
    .json("/tmp")
    .filter(x->{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return true;
    })
    .writeStream()
    .format("parquet")
    .queryName("thisistable")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination();
```

Is there a way for me to avoid this exception and with thrift server get only finished files?